# Use Parallel.Invoke to execute method with parameters

Tags: c#-4.0, action, parallel-processing

I have defined an array of `Action<string, int, double, double>` and want to execute them in parallel using `Parallel.Invoke()`. Is there any way I can cast my Action's to parameterless Actions so that I can do this or is there another way?

Comment: I recommend you add a language tag.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
    {
        YourFirstAction(param1, param2, param3, param4);
    },  // close first Action
    () =>
    {
        YourSecondAction(param1, param2, param3, param4);
    }//close second Action
); //close parallel.invoke
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused as to why the Actions have parameters if you're okay with executing them without sending parameter values. It'd probably be best to use Parallel.ForEach with default values:

```
Action<string, int, double, double>[] actions;

// Action array, actions, set somewhere in code.

Parallel.ForEach(actions, action => action(string.Empty, 0, 0, 0));
```

If you want to send parameters then replace the values as you see fit.

I used the following Actions for my tests:

```
Parallel.For(0, actions.Length, index => actions[index] = (s, i, d1, d2) => Thread.Sleep(100));
Parallel.For(0, parameterless.Length, index => parameterless[index] = () => Thread.Sleep(100));
```

The results for an array of length 20 in seconds:

Parallel.Invoke:  0.3000709

Parallel.ForEach: 0.3022143

Regular for loop: 2.0000706

So Parallel.Invoke does have the advantage of using parameter-less Actions, which does slightly effect performance, but not by much.

Just for kicks, I tested the parameter-less Action array using Parallel.ForEach and the result was just about the same as the Parallel.Invoke with a result of 0.300979 seconds.